# [0]-bash: [: 0*1%8: integer expression expected

Tags: bash

Can someone point out what is wrong with the output.

```
for i in {0..127} ; do 
    echo -n [$i]
    if [ $i*$j%8 -eq 0 ]; then 
        echo "\n"
    fi
    mytool -c "read 0x1540:0xa0:$i*$j"
done
```

I am trying to format the output into rows containing 8 items each.

I tried the suggestion below and modified my code to

```
for i in {0..8} ; for j in {0..16}; do 
    echo -n [$i*$j]
    if [[ $i*$j%8 == 0 ]]; then 
        echo
    fi
    mytool -c "read 0x1540:0xa0:$i*$j"
done
```

Above with `for i in {0..8} ; for j in {0..16}`

I am expecting this to be a nested for loop.I am not very sure if this is how I do a nested loop in bash.

Still the output is not as I expect it.

My output looks like

```
[0]0x3
[1]0x4
[2]0x21
[3]0x1
[4]0x0
[5]0x0
[6]0x4
[7]0x41
[8]0x84
[9]0x80
[10]0x0
[11]0x0
[12]0x3
[13]0x0
[14]0x43
[15]0x49
[16]0x53
[17]0x43
[18]0x4f
[19]0x2d
[20]0x49
[21]0x4e
[22]0x43
[23]0x20
[24]0x0
[25]0x0
[26]0x9
[27]0x3a
[28]0x37
[29]0x34
[30]0x39
[31]0x34
```

I want [0] to [7] in ROW1
       [8] to [15] in ROW2

and so on.

Comment: That needs to be `[[` instead of `[` to work as is. To use `((` also needs `==` instead of `-eq`.

Comment: @EtanReisner - Please see comments above.

Comment: What is the value of `$j`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `(( ))` if you want to do math.

```
if ((i * j % 8 == 0)); then
```

Given your problem description I suggest a bit of a rewrite.

```
for i in {0..15}; do
    for j in {0..7}; do
        echo -n "[$((i * 8 + j))]"
        mytool -c "read 0x1540:0xa0:$i*$j"
    done

    echo
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `test` command (`[` is an alias for `test`, not syntax) requires the expression to be built up from multiple arguments. This means spaces are critical to separate operators and operands. Since each part is a separate argument, you also need to quote the `*` so that the shell does not expand it as a file glob prior to calling `test`/`[`.

```
    if [ "$i" "*" "$j" % 8 -eq 0 ]; then
```

The `test` command expects 7 separate arguments here: `$i`, `*`, `$j`, `%`, `-eq`, and `0`, which it then assembles into an expression to evaluate. It will not parse an arbitrary string into an expression.

As noted by John Kugelman, there are easier ways to accomplish such arithmetic in `bash`.